Under what conditions can the order of the limit and minimization be interchanged in an optimization problem?
Suppose $f(x,t)$ is a real-valued function with two arguments $x$ and $t$, under what conditions can the order of the limit and minimization be interchanged in an optimization problem? Namely, do we have
$$
\underset{t\rightarrow a}{\lim}\,\,\underset{x}{\min}\,\,f\left( x,t \right) =\underset{x}{\min}\,\,\underset{t\rightarrow a}{\lim}\,\,f\left( x,t \right) \tag1
$$
for some well-behaved functions, such as functions that are convex concerning both $x$ and $t$?
I've tried several examples and eq(1) is correct for those examples. For instance, let $f(x,t)=(x+t)^2$, then we have
$$
\underset{t\rightarrow a}{\lim}\,\,\underset{x}{\min}\,\,f\left( x,t \right) =\underset{t\rightarrow a}{\lim}\,\,\underset{x}{\min}\,\,\left( x+t \right) ^2=\underset{t\rightarrow a}{\lim}\,\,0=0\tag2
$$
and
$$
\underset{x}{\min}\,\,\underset{t\rightarrow a}{\lim}\,\,\left( x+t \right) ^2=\underset{x}{\min}\left( x+a \right) ^2=0\tag3,
$$
that is, eq(2) is equal to eq(3).

Assuming $f$ is continuous in $t$-variables, the question is essentially asking whether the minimum is continuous: $$\min_x f(x,a)\stackrel{?}=\lim_{t\to a}\min_x f(x,t)$$ If $f$ is jointly continuous in $x$ and $t$ and if the domain of $x$ is compact, then the answer is affirmative.

@SangchulLee Thank you for the comment! What if the domain of $x$ is not compact? Are there some other properties of $f$, such as $f$ is convex concerning $x$, that can remedy this? I guess the answer is also affirmative as if $f$ is convex concerning $x$, then we can restrict the domain of $x$ into an interval, which is compact.

@narip convexity doesn't mean you can restrict domain of x into an interval

No, in general. The left/right limits can be different. For example, consider function: $$f(x,t) = \begin{cases} 
      tx & t>0 \\
      -1 & t\le 0 
\end{cases}$$

But your function is not continuous for the argument $t$. For instance, when $x=0$, the left limit and the right limit of your function are not equal. This makes the limit of $t$ ill-defined.
